# Magento POST requests throwing 403

Tags: php, json, rest, magento, oauth

I've a magento 1.9.1 community instance setup and I'm trying to access them via REST API . I'm able to perform GET requests for Products/Customers etc but I'm stuck while adding a product using a POST request. My sample code is below. Where am I going wrong ?

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1 as OAuth
import requests
import json

oauth = OAuth(client_key=consumer_key, 
    client_secret=consumer_secret, 
    resource_owner_key=access_key, 
    resource_owner_secret=access_secret)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
           'Accept': 'application/json'}

product = """{
```

"type_id": "simple",
"attribute_set_id": "4",
"sku": "Test",
"name": "Test",
"price": "100",
"description": "Random description",
"short_description": "Random",
"weight": "500",
"status": "1",
"visibility": "4",
"tax_class_id": "2"
}"""

```
payload = json.loads(product)
uri = "http://magentohost/api/rest/products"
r = requests.post(url=uri,  data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers, auth=oauth)
print r
```